# 301 redirect not working through .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I found this little trick http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/301-redirects/ to redirect my old Wordpress domain to my new domain with the path included. I run a test on my local copy and everything works fine. When I log in to the cpanel of the old domain and try it though it gives me some bad results.

Here is the code I used for both my local and live copy ...

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Redirect 301 / http://newsite.com/
```

Here's what the results look like http://www.cuponsmercado.com.br/lojas/. It looks to be calling the new domain (based on the Google Chrome status at the bottom left) but it just shows the old domain with broken HTML/CSS. Any Ideas?

**UPDATE:** 
I was mistakenly editing the same domain when I thought I was editing both. Both were hosted on the same hosting account but displayed separate cPanel URLs leading to the confusion.  There was a chance one .htaccess was conflicting with the other domain as well.

Answer (score 1):

Make this as first rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?cuponsmercado\.com\.br$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.cuponsdemercado.com.br%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: I tried this earlier and again just now and it doesn't solve the problem unfortunately.  Could I hack Wordpress and stop the 'catch-all rule' to work around the issue?

Comment: Ok just keep only `Redirect 301 / http://newsite.com/` line and comment out rest of the lines.

Comment: Also try to test it in a different browser to avoid 301 caching issues in browser.

Comment: Did you try a new browser?

Comment: Problem is that you haven't replaced `http://newsite.com/` with your actual new site name. So it is throwing lots of 404

Comment: Ok I replaced it with `Redirect 301 / http://www.cuponsdemercado.com.br/` and it at least fixed the broken HTML/CSS

Comment: If `http://www.cuponsdemercado.com.br/` is new-site then What is old site's name?

Comment: so everything seems to be working fine. I just opened `http://www.cuponsmercado.com.br/categorias/` and it became `http://www.cuponsdemercado.com.br/categorias/`

Comment: Signing off since it is pretty late here. Leave a comment here and I will attend it my morning.

Comment: Its still not working for me on anything - 3 browsers, iphone.  Thanks for your help though anubhava.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stick with mod_rewrite because a request will get both modules applied (`Redirect` is mod_alias):

Above your `# BEGIN WordPress` section add:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Additionally, you can use mod_alias and get rid of all the old wordpress rules if you are simply moving your site from one server to another.

Comment: I tried this solution, as well as @anubhava's solution, and it didn't do the trick unfortunately.